# Automatically uploading SWC as a GitHub download

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, actionscript-3, git, github

It's a rather annoying process of uploading the newest SWC every time you commit to GitHub. And if you forget to upload the SWC, people will be using old versions.

Is there any way to automate that process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) see links
also you can build SWC From ANT

1) [ant-git-macros](https://github.com/FrancisVarga/ant-git-macros) 
2) [Github ANT Scripts](http://www.newtriks.com/?p=910)

Answer (score 1):

According to GitHub, You can do this automatically by [tagging](http://gitref.org/branching/#tag) a point in your repository.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a Ruby "GitHub Upload" script which was easy enough to include in my build script.
https://github.com/wereHamster/ghup